# How to add an expression to the title of sjp.grpfrq function

Tags: r, sjplot

How can I generate a title like this for sjp.grpfrq function?

[image]

As example, I can generate a text like that with:

```
plot.new()

a <- TeX(sprintf("%s (%s, $N_{HIGH}$=%d/$N_{TOTAL}$=%d)", "Whatever", "Blah", 10, 20))

text(0.5,0.5,a)
```

But I cannot use something like this:

```
sjp.grpfrq(age.group, var.group, showValueLabels = FALSE, title = a)
```

Because I get the following error:

Error in title == "" : comparison is not allowed for expressions

So, how can I generate a title that have subscripts expressions in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add the title afterwards. The function call returns a list with a `$plot` object, where you can add a title with `ggtitle`:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)
sjp.grpfrq(efc$e42dep, efc$e16sex)$plot + ggtitle("New Title")
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks! I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, if my answer is satisfying, would be kind if you could accept it. :-)